# Attacking while moving over enemies with Carriers?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

Is it possible to order a carrier to move over enemy units, while attacking them, but without stopping to attack ? This is useful if you want to make sure you carrier moves to safety or to the enemy's mineral line, but don't want to use the move command because, well, the interceptors seem to be able to attack while the carrier is attack-moving.

Comment: Carriers should do this by default

Comment: Is this the difference between Attack and Move-Attack?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a carrier is idle or attack-moving, it will launch its interceptors against any hostile targets it sees in attack range (range 8). If it's attack-moving, it will also stop in place until out of combat.

If you issue a move order to a carrier that is currently attacking a target, it will continue to attack that target until it dies or moves out of interceptor range (range 14), but will not switch to new ones. (This behavior is inconsistent. If the carrier's target dies while the carrier is moving, occasionally two or three interceptors will not return and switch to other targets. I haven't been able to figure out the exact conditions triggering this.)

([Source](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Carrier) of range numbers)

Comment: You are contradicting yourself in the first paragraph. Typo?

Comment: Is that better? I didn't see any contradiction.

Comment: So, the solution (assuming my first target dies) is to attack other targets and then click move to my destination. Quite messy and not micro-friendly :(

Comment: @Ripper, Once attacking your Carries will continue to attack while there is anything in range.  All you have to do is attack once and then move as necessary.

Comment: @ripper234: Actually, it seems I was a bit wrong. In my tests, sometimes a couple interceptors WILL switch to other targets while the rest return to the carrier. Not enough to really change your conclusion, however.

Comment: My impression was the most interceptors return... I'll test it sometime, currently I'm practicing my zealot rush :)

Comment: I never saw more than 3 interceptors stay out after their target died when the carrier was moving, and most of the time they all returned home.

Comment: By the way, if you're utilizing this maneuver (stop-move), the Graviton Catapult will make the carrier do more damage as it is moving because it will release its interceptors much more quickly on each stop command.

Answer (score 3):

When I am trying to run away with my carriers, I will often quickly alternate between attack-move and regular move. This gets them out of the way while still ensuring that they engage as they run. It IS slower than simply moving them, but it accomplishes the objective of getting them to attack as they move.